# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'magnitude'

Tags: python-3.x, class

```
class Force:
    def __init__(self,magnitude,angle):
        self.magnitude = magnitude
        self.angle = angle

    def get_horizontal(self):
        return self.magnitude * cos(radians(self.angle))

    def get_vertical(self):
        return self.magnitude * sin(radians(self.angle))

    def get_angle(self,use_degrees = True):
        if use_degrees:
            return self.angle
        else:
            return radians(self.angle)

def find_net_force(forces):
        tot_hor = 0
        tot_ver = 0
        for i in forces:
            tot_hor += i.get_horizontal()
            tot_ver += i.get_vertical()

        magnitude = (tot_hor ** 2 + tot_ver ** 2) ** 0.5
        magnitude = round(magnitude,1)
        angle = degrees(atan2((tot_ver),(tot_hor)))
        angle = round(angle,1)

force_1 = Force(50, 90)
force_2 = Force(75, -90)
force_3 = Force(100, 0)
forces = [force_1, force_2, force_3]
net_force = find_net_force(forces)
print(net_force.magnitude)
print(nIt_force.get_angle())
```

When i execute this code i get,
print(net_force.magnitude)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'magnitude'
Where to look for the error, as I can see that something is related to the magnitude part.

Answer (score 0):

It's at the bottom:

```py
print(net_force.magnitude)
```

`the_force` is null because of `find_net_force`'s return value.

The exception you saw should've had a stack trace showing you the line number.

Comment: When I added `return magnitude` it displays, _AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'magnitude'_ . So what does this mean?

Comment: You've made `find_net_force` return a `float` value for storage in the `the_force` variable. `net_force.magnitude` is accessing the "`magnitude`" attribute of the `net_force` variable. `float` values have no `magnitude` attribute.

Comment: Float values have no magnitude attribute in the sense? (Magnitude attribute of net_force should be a float in my case) The magnitude part which I'm returning is a float. So what should be done?

Comment: `the_force` variable?

Comment: the `Force` object itself, `self`.

Comment: `Force` objects are the only Class that have a `magnitude` attribute. Congrats on taking on programming! Why don't you look up a Python tutorial about variables, functions, and classes? I'm sorry, we've all but connected the dots for you, and you should be the one that draws the line. I don't want to be giving out "homework answers".